# Frechet metric: troubles understanding $d(x^{(j)},0)\to0\iff x_i^{(j)}\to0$ $\forall i\in\mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the metric
$$
d(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{1+|x_k-y_k|}
$$on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ with $x=(x_k)$ and $y=(y_k)$.

Let $x^{(j)}\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ for all $j\in\mathbb N$. What does $d(x^{(j)},0)\to0$ iff $x_i^{(j)}\to0$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$ and $j\to\infty$ mean?

I do know how to show it but but having troubles to understand the statement. $x^{(j)}$ is a sequence and so $x_i^{(i)}$ is a sequence of sequences? And then what does $x_i^{(j)}\to0$ mean?

Comment: You need convergence factors, like  $2^{-k}$, for the sum to be defined on all of $\mathbb {R}^{\mathbb {N}}.$

Answer (score 0):

$x_i^{(j)}$ is the i-th term of the sequence $x^{(j)}$, and $x_i^{(j)} \to 0$ means that for all $i$, the sequence $(x_i^{(j)})_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge to $0$.

You can consider this as a double indexed sequence $x_{n,m}$

Comment: No, $x_i^{(j)}$ is a number